Why index is not used for sorting here?
I created PostgreSQL table with test data and wondered why index is not using for sorting:
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    client_id INTEGER,
    total NUMERIC(10, 2),
    created_at TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO orders (client_id, total, created_at)
SELECT 
    (RANDOM() * 100 + 1)::INTEGER AS client_id,          
    1000 * ROUND((RANDOM() * 500)::NUMERIC, 2) AS total,      
    NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' * FLOOR(RANDOM() * 365) 
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

CREATE INDEX ON orders (client_id desc, created_at desc);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM orders WHERE client_id = 7 ORDER BY created_at desc;

It returns
| Sort  (cost=669.05..670.30 rows=500 width=32) (actual time=1.043..1.102 rows=1046 loops=1)                                                         |
|   Sort Key: created_at DESC                                                                                                                        |
|   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 130kB                                                                                                            |
|   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orders  (cost=12.29..646.64 rows=500 width=32) (actual time=0.218..0.854 rows=1046 loops=1)                              |
|         Recheck Cond: (client_id = 7)                                                                                                              |
|         Heap Blocks: exact=517                                                                                                                     |
|         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on orders_client_id_created_at_idx  (cost=0.00..12.17 rows=500 width=0) (actual time=0.162..0.163 rows=1046 loops=1) |
|               Index Cond: (client_id = 7)                                                                                                          |
| Planning Time: 0.230 ms                                                                                                                            |
| Execution Time: 1.160 ms                                                                                                                           |


Execution Time: 1.160 ms, there is a big chance that using an index would make it slower. Not faster. It's sorting a few kilobytes, not gigabytes

Because it thinks that that would be slower.

I tried tables with 10-100 times more rows, an execution plan was the same, while sorting was around 60 ms

The reason that PostgreSQL does not use the index for sorting is that it performs a bitmap index scan, which will return the rows in physical table order rather than in index order.
PostgreSQL chooses the bitmap index scan because it estimates that it will find 500 rows, and if you fetch many rows using an index, a bitmap index scan is more efficient.
The table is too small for the choice to make much difference. If you use a larger table, and experiments show that bitmap index scan plus sort is slower than an index scan, one reason could be that you set random_page_cost too high for your hardware.
